# How could I encrypt based on the previous and next letter?

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to do is encrypt a string with this formula after making it lowercase and removing all the spaces: C_n = P_(n–1) * P_n + P_(n+1)

How do I go about doing this in JS?

Comment: do you have some examples?

Comment: @ninascholz Yes. I encrypted “the” with this method by hand and got “HIE”. How would I automate that in JS?

Comment: do you have a calculation of the wanted result?

Comment: I need your example which you done by your hand can i get that ?

Comment: what are your numeric assignments for the letters? a=1, b=2? why is your example result uppercase when you state you lowercase all?

Answer (score 0):

assuming assignments for a=1, b=2, .. and that position wraps (meaning pos(-1) = 3 for a 4 letter word).

```
function encrypt(str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/, '');
    var len = str.length() - 1;
    var P = (n) => {
        if (n < 0) n = n+len;
        if (n >= len) n = n-len;
        return str.charCodeAt(n) - 64;
    }
    var result = '';
    for (var n = 0; n < len, n++) {
        var c = P(n-1) * P(n) + P(n+1);
        result += String.fromCharCode(c);
    }
    return result;
}
```